# Dynamically generate html files to display image and video

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am uploading some images and videos to  upload folder and then I display those to my webpage using array. that takes extra load on browser.
so I want when I upload any image/video to upload folder it should create dynamic html or php file to display for each image/video.
Can anyone tell me how to do?

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. We are not free coders, but rather people willing to help each other to solve problems

Comment: Creating a php/html file for every image/video is a crazy idea. The whole point of a language like PHP is to write code once, use it multiple times. Your best bet is templates, as mentioned in the answer below. This allows for easier to manage code, cleaner directory structures and better page caching (faster loading times).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to write 2 templates (video and image) and use file_gets_contents and str_replace() and file_put_contents

Example of my idea :

templateVideo.html (or php if you need dynamic)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <video src="YOUR_DYNAMIC_PATH"></video>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php :

```
# ... your code for upload ...

$videoName = 'myFile.mp3';
$myTemplate = file_get_contents('templateVideo.html');

//str_replace(search, replace, subject)
$myTemplate = str_replace('YOUR_DYNAMIC_PATH', $videoName, $myTemplate);

// file_put_contents(filename, data)
file_put_contents('your_path_and_filename', $myTemplate);
```

Something like that :)

NOTE : look at mkdir for create dynamic folder if you need